# Select specific column in Python dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, yfinance

I would like to select a specific field from a python dictionary.  The following code produces a result of 152 lines, but I only want to select one line and output it as a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
AAPL = Ticker('AAPL')
AAPL.earnings_trend
```

Code above returns 152 lines.  Below is a portion of it.

```
{'AAPL': {'trend': [{'maxAge': 1,
    'period': '0q',
     ,
   {'maxAge': 1,
    'period': '-5y',
    'endDate': None,
    'growth': 0.21908002,
    'earningsEstimate': {'avg': {},
     'low': {},
     'high': {},
     'yearAgoEps': {},
     'numberOfAnalysts': {},
     'growth': {}},
     'downLast90days': {}}}],
  'maxAge': 1}}
```

I want to print line 130 as a dataframe (`'growth': 0.21908002` from above):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG']

tickers = Ticker(symbols)
df = pd.DataFrame([{'symbol': ticker, 'growth': data['trend'][-1]['growth']}
                       for ticker, data in tickers.earnings_trend.items()])
print(df)

# Output
  symbol   growth
0   MSFT  0.22542
1   AAPL  0.21908
2   GOOG  0.23349
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

AAPL = Ticker('AAPL')
earnings_trend = AAPL.earnings_trend

# Extract the required value
growth = earnings_trend['AAPL']['trend'][4]['growth']

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'growth': [growth]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     growth
0  0.219080
```

Comment: Thank you, @ma9!  Works great, but can we put the ticker column in there too?  So column one is `ticker` or `symbol` and column 2 is `growth`?